# How to Run scheduled tasks in PHP by a web server

Tags: php, cron

I have uploaded a php base project to domain , which send messages from webpage to mobiles.
For this purpose user open webpage every midnight and the code work well.
My question is can i update my script to send message automatically at midnight without a user open that page in browser?
i searched and find a result of cron-job. if it is right that with cron-job a domain send messages without any laptop or computer browser than please give me scripts of how to use cron-job in php. because i am totally new to cron-job.
otherwise please suggest me a way of doing such job. thanks

Comment: Check administrative pages of your host provider. They usualy have a way to schedule a 'visit' to a specific page like this.

Comment: Invoke the cron job via wget/curl and its web URL then. (From the phrasing it sounds unlikely that this is a factual requirement though.)

Comment: as i am totally new to this topic please tell me which first step should i take ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the crontab feature inside a linux server

crontab -e

and then enter it like this:

- - - - - wget -O /dev/null "{URL_GOES_HERE}" > /dev/null 2>&1

Of course change the {URL_GOES_HERE} to the real url. This will run every minute, if you want to run per 5 min or equal then you can checkout the link on wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: By the way it should be stars * in the first part. And also you need the wget command to get this working, most of the server supplier should have this already in place.

Comment: thanks dear i will try but where should i enter this code. in a php file ?

Comment: No, the code goes into your linux terminal. So inside a linux server run the following command.

crontab -e